# Entering SSID and PSK password in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wifi, ssid, wpa2-psk

I have a bit of a C# conundrum.

We have an C# application that needs to set a WPA2-PSK SSID and password. The IEEE spec says that the SSID is a 32 octet value.  The issue is that you can set any valid 32 byte value. Non-ascii characters can appear differently on different platforms depending on the code page used, and not all code pages can generate all possible 8 bit byte values.  Ditto for password with up to 63 bytes.  Since we have international customers, they could be using just about anything?

Short of having a WPF dialog that allows you to specify both display and hex characters, any suggestions on how to get these entered?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difficulty.  Wouldn't each customer naturally only be entering characters in their local character set/code-page?

Comment: Yes, but that codepage may or may not match the codepage used on the access point.  For example, if I put a 0x80 into my SSID, windows reports that as one character and my phone reports it as another.  What I really need is a way to enter an SSID/password in the native character set with a way to verify it in, say hex and allow the user to edit it.  

This is a fairly pervasive bug in that it was an issue in Vista (stop laughing) as well as most of the other solutions I have found.

Comment: Any chance you could change the login UI to allow the user to select their language/culture while entering passwords?

Comment: In the case of things like Windows, using the German version of Windows will automatically change the codepage.  The problem is then getting those characters into a byte array that is in some way similar to what the AP is translating.  Thus the need to have a flexible enough program to handle all the permutations.